# Oracle doesn't remove cursors after closing result set and statement, while using PreparedStatement

Tags: java, jdbc, oracle11g, cursor, prepared-statement

I am facing issue in preparedStatement . Open cursor count increases every time preparedStatement is created and executed and it does not come down .
I am closing the result, statement after each execution .
Just to make sure things are not happening due to some other piece of code, I created  a simple jsp and executed code into it .

```
 Connection connection = null;
Set<Long> prodIds = new HashSet<Long>();
prodIds.add(5877462198L);
prodIds.add(782414147L);
prodIds.add(5547149987L);
prodIds.add(550424780L);
prodIds.add(5547045538L);
prodIds.add(5883926198L);
prodIds.add(5537432075L);
prodIds.add(81317072L);
prodIds.add(5618071249L);
prodIds.add(5630549908L);
prodIds.add(698964409L);
prodIds.add(822090000L);
prodIds.add(614679729L);
prodIds.add(5512339613L);
prodIds.add(81317068L);
prodIds.add(5688111900L);
prodIds.add(5512339611L);
prodIds.add(5894594380L);
prodIds.add(969040343L);
prodIds.add(827515204L);
prodIds.add(5626593095L);
prodIds.add(501511677L);
prodIds.add(1094656287L);
prodIds.add(5560791888L);
prodIds.add(641347103L);
prodIds.add(786034417L);
prodIds.add(774821382L);
prodIds.add(5599522282L);
prodIds.add(5591420268L);
prodIds.add(660541300L);
prodIds.add(82846941L);
prodIds.add(5529315772L);
prodIds.add(895683920L);
prodIds.add(5547045523L);
prodIds.add(801472476L);
prodIds.add(687163631L);
prodIds.add(5682795171L);
prodIds.add(5547045563L);
prodIds.add(687163630L);


 try {
        Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
         connection = DataSources.getDefaultDataSource().getConnection();
        out.println("connected....!!");
     List<List<Long>> partitionedProductIdsList = Lists.partition(new ArrayList<Long>(prodIds), 1);
     for (List<Long> productIdsList : partitionedProductIdsList) {
             String sql = "SELECT * FROM RECLASSIFY_PRODUCTS_BULK_LOG WHERE  product_id = " + productIdsList.get(0);
                sql += "AND clsf_id = ? ";
             PreparedStatement pstmt = null;
             ResultSet rs = null;
             int paramIndex = 1;
             try {
                pstmt = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
                pstmt.setLong(paramIndex, 203L);
                rs = pstmt.executeQuery();
                while (rs.next()) {
                    out.println(rs.getLong("PRODUCT_ID"));
                }
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                out.println("Exception : " + e.getMessage() + "");
            } finally {
                JdbcUtils.closeQuietly(rs, pstmt);

            }
        }
     out.println("Closing the connection");
    } catch (Exception e) {
     out.println("Exception : " + e.getMessage() + "");
 }
finally {
     try {
         connection.close();
     }
     catch (SQLException e)
     {
         out.println("SQLException : " + e.getMessage() + "");
     }
 }
```

And here is the result from the query :-

```
select a.value, s.username, s.sid, s.serial#
 from v$sesstat a, v$statname b, v$session s
 where a.statistic# = b.statistic# and s.sid=a.sid
 and b.name = 'opened cursors current' and machine = 'v-b10' order by    a.value desc
```

Initially

`VALUE USERNAME    SID SERIAL#
610 UBDB    494 1485
4   UBDB    323 16275
2   UBDB    225 41357
0   UBDB    102 14729`

After loading the jsp

```
VALUE   USERNAME    SID SERIAL#
687 UBDB    494 1485
4   UBDB    323 16275
2   UBDB    225 41357
0   UBDB    102 14729
```

Please help me and let me know if I am doing anything wrong here .

Comment: Try to use this: try-with-resources. *In JDK7, that AutoCloseable list includes java.sql.CallableStatement, Connection, PreparedStatement, Statement, ResultSet, and *RowSet.* https://blogs.oracle.com/WebLogicServer/entry/using_try_with_resources_with

Comment: Currently, we are using JDK6 on production and I need to fix it in the same version .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was some issue in DBCP pool, we were using. It is also reported in following jira ticket .
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/DBCP-397

In case you still want to continue using same pool version, the workaround is to either have all parameters used in where clause to be passed in PreparedStatement  or simply use Statement in place of it .

Answer (score 0):

The `JdbcUtils.closeQuietly(rs, pstmt)` you use is not working. Try to close your rs and stmt manually:

```
if(rs != null){
  try{
    rs.close();
  }catch(Exception AllException){
    AllException.printStackTrace();
  }
}
if(pstmt != null){
  try{
    pstmt .close();
  }catch(Exception AllException){
    AllException.printStackTrace();
  }
}
```

Furthermore, in order to take benefit from binding mechanism, you should create and close your prepared statement one time only, out of your `for` loop.

Comment: Hi romg, I tried the same . Code for `JdbcUtils.closeQuietly(rs, pstmt)` is `public static final void closeQuietly(ResultSet rs, PreparedStatement ps) {
  closeQuietly(rs);
  closeQuietly(ps);
 }
public static final void closeQuietly(PreparedStatement ps) {
  if(ps != null) {
   try {
    ps.close();
   } catch (SQLException e) {
    logger.error("Error when closing prepared statement", e);
   }
  }
 }
public static final void closeQuietly(ResultSet rs) {
  if(rs != null) {
   try {
    rs.close();
   } catch (SQLException e) {
    logger.error("Error when closing resultset", e);
   }
  }
 }`

Comment: I tried closing  rs and stmt manually . The result is same i.e. there are open cursors left after loop exits .